# Wordwrap makes a page blank

Tags: php, word-wrap

When I'm using:

```
echo wordwrap($post['text']);
```

the page appears blank (exactly as in case if the `error_reporting` or `display_errors` in php.ini are disabled, but they're enabled , so thats not an error).

I don't really know why it happens.

When I use:

```
echo $post['text'];
```

It is showing up my text fine. Where is the problem?

## edited

Now, when I use:

```
$text = wordwrap ($post['text']);
echo $text;
```

The function doesn't seems to work, because I still see one long line filled with `aaaaaaaa[...]` and it don't wrap my text.

Comment: Do you have the source for wordwrap(), as well as the contents of $post['text']?

Comment: Are you using a version of PHP *equal to or after* version **4.0.2**?

Comment: @JaredFarrish , I'm using 5.3~.

Comment: Insert `set_error_handler("var_dump");` at the top of the script. And in case of blank pages or http error 500, always check your webservers `error.log`.

Comment: What you've posted doesn't *appear* to be a problem: http://codepad.org/DZRYrn4j

Comment: I got it working right now, I've just added an variable: $text = wordwrap($post['text']);` and then `echo $text;` but it don't wrap my text: I got one, long line: `bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb[...]` ( don't treat it like a spam `:P` )

Comment: edited by question, I hope its ok with editing questions.

Comment: http://codepad.org/f4Br2zPj ??? You haven't provided any way to reproduce, verify and treat your problem.

Comment: When you view the text as one long string, are you viewing it through the browser or the command line?  `wordwrap` does not insert `<br />`, it inserts line breaks by default.

Comment: @Jared Farrish How about http://codepad.org/XLhZzFEi ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you have looooooong text with no space in it. The way wordwrap work is by breaking it using space. If you want to force it to split text even if it has no space or in the middle of the word, you have to tell wordwrap to do so:

```
<?php
$post = array('test'=>'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa');

$text = wordwrap($post['test'], 80, "\n", true);
echo $text;
?>
```

Read [the official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) for more detail.

Comment: Thanks! Working like a charm :-)!